# Type of array of const elements

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, standards-compliance

is it specified in standard that array of const elements has different type than array of non-const elements? Here is my code and output of VC2010 and GCC4.8.0.

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <ios>
int main(){
    int arr_a[] = {1, 2};
    int const arr_b[] = {3, 4}; // or const int arr_b[] = {3, 4};
    std::cout << typeid(arr_a).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(arr_b).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Same type: " << std::boolalpha << (typeid(arr_a) == typeid(arr_b)) << ".\n";
}

int [2]
int const [2]
Same type: false.

A2_i
A2_i
Same type: true.
```

Comment: GCC's `typeid` seems to ignore top-level `const`, but don't trust it.

Comment: @gx_ Trust it! Top level `const` is ignored by 5.2.8/5. The question is, if `const int a[2]` has a **top level `const`**.

Comment: Yes, `const int a[2]` is a _cv-qualified_ type (see 8.3.4 and 3.9.3). Hence, the output of gcc is right. But the types of `arr_a`and `arr_b` are distinct. You cannot use `typeid`, if you want to distinguish types with respect to cv-qualifiers.

Comment: For array, cv-qualifier applies to sub-object, it's not top level.

Comment: @MWid I mean, don't trust `typeid` to know if 2 types are the same, especially when it comes to `const` (nice reference to the Standard, thanks)

Comment: @billz Note, that the meaning of a _cv-qualifier_ has nothing to do with being top-level or not. So, `const int a[2]` has type _array of 2 const int_, but the type of `a` is _cv-qualified_. Ignoring this top-level const means, replacing the type of `a` by _array of 2 int_.

Answer (score 2):

The C++11 standard actually says (3.9.3/1)  (emphasis mine)

> [...] The cv-qualified or
>   cv-unqualified versions of a type **are distinct types**; however, they shall have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements

with the following precision:

> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions,
>   return values from functions, and non-static data members of unions

Answer (score 0):

As stated, typeid().name() isn't a great choice, because the result is implementation defined. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void array_function(const int a[]) {
   cout << "const int a[]" << endl;
}

void array_function(int a[]) {
   cout << "int a[]" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    const int carray[] = { 1, 2, 3};
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3};
    array_function(carray);
    array_function(array);
}
```

It'll show you that the compiler can tell the difference. (The type *is* different.)